# Making a tooltip appear where the mouse is, random behavior?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I want a speech bubble-like tooltip to appear where the mouse is after some text has been selected. And it does work, but when you scroll down and try it out near the end of the document (if it's a long one), it doesn't work. It's quite random. Sometimes the tooltip appears close to the beginning of the document, or it might appear too far to the left, or to the right, or only a portion of it might appear, or it might not appear at all.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bdAbZ/

Here's the code:

```
// Generate the speech bubble
// Temporary placeholder
var $speechBubble = $('<p class="speech-bubble"></p>');
$speechBubble.appendTo('body');

var mousePosition;
function updateMousePosition(event) {
    /* Update the global variable mousePosition with the current location of the mouse.
    */
    mousePosition = {left: event.pageX, top: event.pageY};
}
$(document).mousemove(updateMousePosition); // mousePosition will always be up-to-date.

function getSelectedText() {
    /* Return the text that the user has selected.
    **
    ** If he hasn't selected anything, return an empty string.
    */

    // Different browsers, different ways of getting the selected text.
    if (window.getSelection) {
        return window.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.getSelection) {
        return document.getSelection();
    }
    else if (document.selection) {
        return document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    else {
        // This should normally never happen.
        alert('Could not get the selected text.')
        return false;
    }
}

$('p').mouseup(function() {
    /* Check if the user has selected any text within the p area.
    **
    ** If he has, show the speech bubble menu.
    */
    var selectedText = getSelectedText();
    if (selectedText != '') {
        $speechBubble.text(selectedText);
        $speechBubble.offset(mousePosition);
        $speechBubble.show();
    }
});

$(document).mouseup(function() {
    /* Check if no text has been selected.
    **
    ** If no text has been selected, hide the speech bubble menu.
    **
    ** Why? The user would probably try to get rid of the speech bubble by clicking somewhere else.
*/
    if (getSelectedText() == '') {
        $speechBubble.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Mind creating a fiddle? It would be much easier to troubleshoot your issue.

Comment: dont forget to show getSelectedText function

Comment: Do you want the mouse position or the selected text position? I've been working on a project that does this except it places the tooltip based on the selection rather than the mouse which seems more desireable...

Comment: @frshca The selected text position would actually be great, my only concern is that it might not display in the proper position if the text is selected backwards.

Comment: @MarcoPetersen - I have a solution for that case as well. I will go ahead and make a fiddle for you to show how this is done. Please be patient, it might take several minutes.

Comment: @MarcoPetersen I apologize, the code I have will not work for this situation. I will add a fiddle that should work for the mouse position.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/bdAbZ/8/

The bubble is positioned absolutely now.
I also centered the speech bubble according to the cursor on the mouseup.

Let me know if this works for you...

UPDATE: I updated a couple things like I removed your mousemove listener since that can hog a lot of memory. You don't need to update your cursor position until the mouseup event. I also properly delegated your mouseup listener to the paragraphs. This is all assuming it doesn't disrupt any code you have not shown us: http://jsfiddle.net/bdAbZ/9/

Comment: This works perfectly! Thanks a million! Do you think $('p').mouseup() was the cause of the problem?

Comment: You needed to position the tooltip absolutely, that was the first big piece. But your updateMousePosition() was running slow because it was on a mousemove listener that was covering your entire document which would be the reason for a correlation with larger errors in larger documents. Just remember, keep your event listeners as close as you can to their parent. Take a look here: http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-performa